# Backbone: mixing html and javascript in template

Tags: backbone.js

In this "hello world" example of a Backbone app http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/5.html, the author renders a template inline like this

```
render: function(){
      $(this.el).html('<span style="color:black;">'+this.model.get('part1')+' '+this.model.get('part2')+'</span> &nbsp; &nbsp; <span class="swap" style="font-family:sans-serif; color:blue; cursor:pointer;">[swap]</span> <span class="delete" style="cursor:pointer; color:red; font-family:sans-serif;">[delete]</span>');
      return this; // for chainable calls, like .render().el
    },
```

which, although functional, is a bit of an unmanageable html concatenation.

I've seen authors of other Backbone apps set a template in the view using underscore's template function

```
template: _.template($('#my-template').html()),
```

and then render it instead of the html

```
$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

I wanted to try this technique with the hello world app, but when I created the template file, I ran into the problem that it wasn't strictly html. As you'll notice it calls functions

```
 this.model.get('part2')
```

and the template that I was using as a model (from another author's app, see below) just included html.

Question, What would I need to do to include javascript and html in the same template file so I can make a call to the model?

```
<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
      <div class="company">
        <div class="display">
          <span class="company-text"></span>
          <span class="company-mood">
            <span class="mood"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="company-destroy"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="edit">
          <input class="company-input" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>
```

Comment: You mean these? `<% // arbitrary javascript here %>`

Comment: @orangewarp within that example template shown in the OP, I could include arbitrary javascript within <% %> ?  does that come out of the box with backbone?

Comment: It's a part of Underscore, the dependency that Backbone has so if you're using Backbone, you're good with Underscore's templating system. Heck, the _.template() function is an Underscore function. :-) I've included a link in the answer that can help you figure out how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this link [Underscore Template](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) for details on what you want to accomplish.

But in general, if you just wanted to interpolate your `this.model.get('someAttr');` all you'd need to do is include this in your template.

```
// Since you call it like this:
$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

// Just include this
<div>
    <%= someAttr %>
</div>
```

You're basically passing in the model attributes object and the underscore template just interpolates the properties of that object. You can pass in anything you want although what you do with the render call is what's probably most common.